# Xcode label text color change by using RGB values

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uilabel

***Working on xCode 4.5.1 Interface builder:***

When I try to change the color property of a label's text by using the RGB values, the background color also changes to the same value automatically.

**In other words:**

While setting the RGB values for text colour of labels, the background colour also changes unless we use the sliders.

How to make sure that only the color of text changes and not the background?

Comment: **.m** file is not to be changed. I have to do it via interface builder only.

Answer (score 12):

`UILabel` class has properties `textColor` and `backgroundColor`. You can manipulate them.

```
label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

to work with it via Interface Builder you should choose your label then go to the Attributes inspector. There you'll find section named Label. There's Color tab there. it's for text color. Below Label Section there's a section named View. It contains tab named Background. You can set your background color there

Comment: Thanks Andrey; we are working in a team and don't have the permission to change the .m code for now. Is there a way to do it via interface builder itself?

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I have been using the same procedure but somehow when I use the color lab in Label section and try to enter the RGB values via  keyboard, it automatically sets the same values for the background as well.
Only if I use the slider controls in the color lab, the background color remains the same.

This seems to be more of an IDE setting/error now.

Answer (score 3):

first you need to create 3 uislider on ViewController.h

in viewController.m

```
-(IBAction)Sliders{

label.textColor = [UIColor ColorWithRed:RSlider.value green:GSlider blue:BSlider alpha:1.0f];

}
```

connection should be "Value Changed"